# Operator overloading inside struct

Tags: c++11, operator-overloading

Why i need to make friend keyword if every member of strct is public.

Example:

```
struct Vector{
    int x, y;
    
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &COUT, const Vector &v){
        std::cout << "x: " << v.x << " y: " << v.y;
        return COUT;
    }
    
};
```

Why can't it be like this:

```
struct Vector{
    int x, y;
    
    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &COUT, const Vector &v){
            std::cout << "x: " << v.x << " y: " << v.y;
        return COUT;
    }
    
};
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be a friend, but non-friend free functions can't be defined inside a struct or class, they need to be outside.

Comment: Your second example defines a member function. But your first example does not define a member function, instead it defines a non-member (i.e., free) function, and immediately declares it to be a `friend` of the structure.